# Identify all cells that have been conditionally formatted

Tags: excel, vba, object, conditional-formatting

I am trying to remove duplicate values **except** the first one.

My solution to this was to conditionally format all duplicates, then, working backwards, clear contents of the formatted cells. This would mean that the first one will stop being formatted once all duplicates are removed.

What I have been trying:

```
For i = LaC To 5 Step -1
LR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, LaC).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 2 To LR
    cond = (ws.Cells(j, i).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColourIndex.Value)
        If cond = 22 Then
            ws.Cells(j, i).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Basically, if I try `ws.Cells(j, i).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColourIndex` in the immediate window, it returns 22.

However, if I try this code, I get error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't overthink. It is too complicated to detect the conditional formatting. If you just want to remove duplicates use the [Range.RemoveDuplicates method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.removeduplicates).

Comment: I'd suggest scratch the volatile conditional formatting and just remove duplicates in the column. It would leave the first values alone. Ha, basically what @Pᴇʜ mentioned =)

Comment: What is `LaC`?  Is it a number greater than 0?  **Which line throws the error?**

Comment: Hi, thank you for the info, but the issue is that it must go backwards through the columns.

Basically, it's determining how many work packages must be completed if the deliverables are submitted in different orders. So once a work package is complete, it must be removed from the following deliverables.

Comment: LaC is last column... It goes backwards through the columns. It is the **cond = (ws.Cells(j, i).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColourIndex** that throws the error, even though it works in the immediate window

Comment: ColourIndex >> ColorIndex

Comment: It was just that problem!! Thank you @Tim Williams !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ans: I was writing Colour instead of Color.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not necessary to use VBA you can get rid of duplicates in the GUI via “Data” → “Data Tools” → “Remove Duplicates”. Or, in current versions of Excel O365, you can use the `UNIQUE`-function like this

```
UNIQUE(A:A)
```

assuming your source data is in row `A`. This will keep up with changing data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
However, the problem is that the data is across multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

Check this line more carefully:

```
cond = (ws.Cells(j, i).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColourIndex.Value)
```

`ColorIndex` is a Property, not an `Object`.  As such, `ColorIndex.Value` will return an error.  Note that you *haven't* included the `.Value` when testing in the Immediate Window, and it works as expected:

```
?ws.Cells(j, i).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColourIndex 'This will work
?ws.Cells(j, i).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColourIndex.Value 'This will err
```

Also, there is no need for you to put it in brackets, either:

```
cond = ws.Cells(j, i).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColourIndex
```

Comment: Hi, I've edited the code as you suggested, but the same error is showing. I did Dim cond as Variant, could that possibly be the issue?

Comment: @Confused Unlikely: `ColorIndex` [is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.interior.colorindex) a `Variant` itself.

Comment: Thank you for the info... Just can't understand why it will work in immediate but not in the code! Very troublesome haha